# Why JSP not running this 'if(s1.equals(s3))' statement even if the condition is true for it?

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, jdbc

I wrote a program where a user inputs username and password which gets stored into the database.But first ResultSet query checks if the username input is already available in the database and then runs the codeblock in the 'if' statement and doesnt add the username input. Else it does. But in this program whenever user is inputting data , it is inserted into the browser even if the user input matches the username query in the database

Form:

```
<body>
    <form name="loginForm" method="post" action="log.jsp">
        Username:<input type="text" name="user" />
        <br/>
        PassWord:<input type="password" name="pass">
        <br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign Up!">
    </form>

</body>
```

log.jsp:

```
<%@ page import= "java.sql.*" %>


    <%
        String s1=request.getParameter("user");
        String s2=request.getParameter("pass");

        Connection con=null;
        Statement st=null;
        ResultSet rs=null;

        try{

            Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");
            con=DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:xe","system","pass");

            if (s1.equals("") || s2.equals("")){
                out.println("<script>alert('Please Enter valid credentials');</script>");

            }
            else{
                st=con.createStatement();
                rs=st.executeQuery("select users from NewUsers");
                while(rs.next()){
                    String s3=rs.getString("users");
                    if(s1.equals(s3)){
                        out.println("Username already exists");
                    }
                    else{
                        try{
                           st.executeUpdate("insert into NewUsers(users,pass) values('"+s1+"','"+s2+"')");
                        }
                        catch(SQLException sql){}
                        finally{
                            out.println("Signed Up , Go here for login:<a href='login.jsp'>Here</a> ");  
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException cnfe){}
        finally{
            if(st!=null)try{st.close();}catch(SQLException ignore){}
            if(rs!=null)try{rs.close();}catch(SQLException ignore){}
            if(con!=null)try{con.close();}catch(SQLException ignore){}
        }

        %>
```

I dont understand why even after not putting anything the input , the else statement is not executing? Is there some default value in the input?

Edit:
Figured it out:

```
ps=con.prepareStatement("select users from NewUsers u where u.users=?");
ps.setString(1,s1);
rs=ps.executeQuery();
if(rs.next()){
out.println("<script>alert('User already exists')</script>");
 }else{//dbUpdate}
```

Comment: Make yourself a favor and avoid using scriptlets in JSP.

Comment: What would you recommended? I have heard about the disadvantages of scriptlets.

Comment: Read here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3177733/1065197

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your logic is completely flawed. To check if the *entered* user exists in the database, you execute a query that loads **all** the users from the database. Then you loop over **all** the users, and, for **each** user, if it's different from the entered one, you insert the new user.

That doesn't make sense.

Use a SQL query that checks if the **entered** user exists in the database. Since your next mistake will be to use String concatenation to create that SQL query, avoid doing that mistake and learn to use [prepared statements](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), containing parameters:

```
select users from NewUsers u where u.users = ?
```

PS: actually, you're *already* doing that mistake, making your code vulerable to SQL injection attacks, and not working as soon as there is a single quote in the user name or password.

Comment: No. As my answer explains, with a link to the appropriate tutorial, it would be done using a **prepared** statement.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Can you please elaborate, how the code would lead to sql attacks? I am a beginner . I would appreciate any knowledge i can get .

Comment: @chanchalkarn: The exact phrase that JB Nizet used -- "SQL injection attacks" -- appears hundreds of thousands of times on the Web. The first Google-hit is a detailed Wikipedia article. Please put in a little bit of effort.

Comment: I searched for it . I meant referring to this code . So that next time i see this mistake , i will solve it .